# Tasks are pending in Celery[redis] in Flask on Railway

Tags: flask, redis, celery, background-process, railway

I have made a flask api and it is deployed on railway. There are some tasks that I have tried to made them background tasks using Celery. I am getting task backend and task id in the print but task.state is always pending and I have only few tasks in the [image: redis @ railway]. Only one task is created for each deployment I think.
Here is how I have tried to use celery.

```
"""
path: tasks.py

Celery tasks.
"""
import pandas as pd
from celery import shared_task
from celery.contrib.abortable import AbortableTask

from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount


@shared_task(bind=True, base=AbortableTask)
def fetch_insights_task(self, account_id):
    """
    Get insights from Facebook Ads API.
    """
    params = {
        'level': 'campaign',
        'date_preset': 'yesterday',
        'time_increment': 1,
        'breakdowns': ['gender', 'age'],
        }

        .
        .
        .
    return insights
```

```
# path: views.py

@main.route('/insights')
def get_insights():
    """
    Insights page
    """
    if 'account_id' not in session:
        return redirect('/select_account')

    task_id = session.get('insights_task_id')
    task = fetch_insights_task.AsyncResult(task_id) if task_id else None
    .
    .
```

```
"""
Utils
"""
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    """
    Make celery
    """
    celery = Celery(app.import_name)
    celery.conf.update(app.config["CELERY_CONFIG"])
    celery.conf.update(
        task_serializer='json',
        result_serializer='json',
        accept_content=['json'],
        timezone='UTC')

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        """
        Context task
        """
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

```
celery -A run:celery worker --loglevel=debug -P solo
```

I was expeting the tasks to be colmpleted. But the tasks are always in pending state.

Comment: I found that in railway I am using the code below in Procfile.

    web: gunicorn application:application
    broker: celery -A celery_worker:celery worker --loglevel=debug --concurrency=4 --pool=solo

Due to which only web is running. If I setup start command to celery command then only celery is run. How can I run both

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make two start commands with Railway using Procfile, railway.toml, railway.json or railway.sh and all faild to run two commands.

**railway always execute the first start command** and ignore the rest.

The only method that worked with me is to run two railway services connected to the same project repo with the two different single start commands for each.

**in your case:**

first service start command is

> "gunicorn app:app"

second service start command is

> "celery -A run:celery worker --loglevel=debug -P solo"

also you can change solo to thread if you want to run received tasks all in parallel.

[A Typical case of your railway environment will be as this snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHrpK.png)